# Best way to index a SQL table to find best matching string

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Let's say I have a SQL table with an `int` PK column and an `nvarchar(max)`. In the the `nvarchar(max)` column, I have a bunch of table entries that are all like this:

```
SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES
SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_TUESDAY
SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON
SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON_CAFE
SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_RIVER
.
.
.
SOME_ANTS_HATE_SYRUP
SOME_ANTS_HATE_SYRUP_WITH_STRAWBERRIES
```

There's millions of these rows - Then let's say my goal is to find the row with the most overlap for an input `searchTerm` - So in this case, if I input `SOME PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON_MOUNTAIN`, the returned entry would be the third entry from the table above, `SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON`

I have a SPROC that does this very naively, it goes through the entire table as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phrase, len(phrase) l, [id] FROM X WHERE searchTerm LIKE phrase + '%'

-- phrase is the row entry being searched against
-- searchTerm is the phrase we're searching for
```

I then `ORDER BY` length and pick the `TOP` only

Would there be a way to speed this up, perhaps by doing some indexing?

If this is confusing, think of it as `tableRowEntry + wildcard = searchTerm`

I'm on MSSQL 2008 if that makes any difference

Comment: Your query should make use of an index on `searchTerm`, assuming that `phrase` is really a constant parameter.

Comment: Matt, see my update with example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an index on your NVARCHAR-column a `LIKE 'Something%'` -search will be able to use it and should be pretty fast.

If there is a wildcard in the beginning you are out of luck. But - in your case - this should work.

You might use an indexed persistant computed column storing the length of the string. In this case you might reduce the workload enormously by filtering out all string which are to short or to long.

If there are certain words in your search terms which appear often but not everywhere, you might use side columns again and filter like `AND InlcudePEOPLE=1 AND IncludeMOON=1`

### UPDATE

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE Phrase(ID INT IDENTITY
                   ,Phrase NVARCHAR(100)
                   ,PhraseLength AS LEN(Phrase) PERSISTED);
CREATE INDEX IX_Phrase_Phrase ON Phrase(Phrase);
CREATE INDEX IX_Phrase_PhraseLength ON Phrase(PhraseLength);

INSERT INTO Phrase
VALUES
 ('SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES')
,('SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_TUESDAY')
,('SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON')
,('SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON_CAFE')
,('SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_RIVER')
,('SOME_ANTS_HATE_SYRUP')
,('SOME_ANTS_HATE_SYRUP_WITH_STRAWBERRIES');

DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(100)=N'SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON_MOUNTAIN';
```

--This uses the index (checked against execution plan)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Phrase 
WHERE @SearchTerm LIKE Phrase + '%'
ORDER BY PhraseLength DESC;
```

--This might be even better, check with your high row count.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Phrase
WHERE Phrase=LEFT(@SearchTerm,PhraseLength)
ORDER BY PhraseLength DESC;
GO
```

--Clean-Up

```
DROP TABLE Phrase;
```

Comment: IMHO, OP can't really filter out too long and too short results since he's looking for closest match. What if the closest match is not the exact match in terms of length?

Comment: @KamilG. well, it would be necessary to define *closest* ... Strings which are to long should be sorted out - at least I understand it this way...

Comment: I believe an edge case would be when there is only one match for the search term and it's distance in length from the searching phrase is huge, but it should still account it. Eg: searching phrase len = 10, found only one match with len = 1000.

Comment: @KamilG. I just added some example (without a length check, this might be done additionally, depending on the actual business case)

Comment: Thanks, I understood your prior point. Something that doesn't appeal to me is filtering out before applying a limit - I believe there are more than less cases in which you can't specify that.

Comment: @KamilG. My thought was: Any string longer than `SOME_PEOPLE_LIKE_APPLES_ON_THE_MOON_MOUNTAIN` cannot be *equal* to the search string. This means, one could skip all phrases with a length higher than the search term. But we cannot know this...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution here is to create a full-text search index:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Full text search is optimized for this task, once the index is created you can use full-text queries with the CONTAINS full-text function to find the matches efficiently:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phrase, len(phrase) l, [id] FROM X WHERE CONTAINS(phrase, searchPhrase)
```

Full text search not only allows custom optimization through query hints like `OPTIMIZE FOR`, it also allows for stopwords like AND and OR within the search terms, and a variety of other text-searching goodies, like being able to find spelling variations of the same word automatically and filter by relevance, etc..